# How to mock __next__ magic method?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

How to mock `Queue.__next__` magic method? The code below with `side_effect` is not working:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [1, 2, 3]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            num = self.nums.pop()
        except Exception:
            raise StopIteration
        return num


class Consumer:

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self._queue = queue

    def consume(self):
        for msg in self._queue:
            raise ValueError(msg)


def test_it():
    queue = MagicMock()
    queue.__next__.side_effect = [4, 5, 6]  # not working
    consumer = Consumer(queue)
    consumer.consume()
```

Python interpreter is not even going inside `__next__` method. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `__iter__` method returns nothing.

```
def test_it():
    queue = MagicMock()
    queue.__iter__.return_value = [4, 5, 6]
    consumer = Consumer(queue)
    consumer.consume()
```

Comment: Oh. So if I mock `Queue.__iter__` method then method `Queue.__next__` is not called but instead called `__next__` of list [4,5,6], right?